# View "Run/Debug Configurations" duration/start/end timing

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When running "Run/Debug Configurations" I often doubt about how long it has been running. I wonder if there's a built in option which shows duration or start/end timestamps for configurations? In my shell I have a timestamp on each new line which gives a kind of indication about duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet possible. Here's a request for that on our tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77560/Timestamps-in-the-Run-console